# Remove all directories in output of find and redirect output to new file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, find, text-formatting

If my find output looks like this:

```
/var/log/data/run/account1.ext
```

How can I trim off everything except the "account1" and redirect into a file?

Note: this is just an example the actual folders found may vary in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **sed**:

```
$ echo "/var/log/data/run/account1.ext" | sed -e 's/.*\/\(\w\+\).*/\1/g'
account1
```

With redirection:

```
$ echo "/var/log/data/run/account1.ext" | sed -e 's/.*\/\(\w\+\).*/\1/g' > my_file
```